# Increase mouse cursor size when moved rapidly

Tags: 22.04, macosx, cursor

In MacOS, there is a feature that if the mouse cursor is moved rapidly, it increases in size (so that the cursor can be easily spotted). Once stopped, it gets back to normal size.

Can something like this be achieved in Ubuntu?

I am using Ubuntu 22.04. I am open to using Kubuntu or any other flavor where this can be incorporated.

---

What I tried - The following script toggles the mouse cursor size in GNOME/Unity.

```
if gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface cursor-size | grep -q 24
then
    gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface cursor-size 48;
else
    gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface cursor-size 24;
fi
EOF
```

If it can be executed on rapid mouse movement/when cursor is moved in a circular manner, we are done.